# Which type of inheritance is more preferable?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

Is the only point in implementing the 2nd case is if I want to derive from a Collidable without being an Object? If that's the case, when is the 1st case ever favorable since the 2nd case offers more flexibility.

Both collidables have only a pure virtual function and Object is a base class for objects that can be drawn on the screen (in my case).

^Assuming I'm understanding the following code correctly (I'm not too sure TBH)

```
class Object
class CollidableObject : Object
class Actor : public CollidableObject

class Object
class Collidable
class Actor : public Object, public Collidable
```

Edit:

Based on Matt/Seth

```
class Object
class Collidable
class Clickable
class Trackable
class BlowUppable
class Actor : public Object, public Collidable, public Clickable, public Trackable,
              public BlowUppable

class SomeObjectThatIsTakenForGrantedThatEverythingElseIsInherited : public Actor
```

First example is the second case and second example is the first case. I guess thats the only use I see for the first case.

@Luchian
This is going to be a different question from the original since your reply was neither.

In this case, is there a difference changing an object from a is-a to a has-a relationship? In each case, to check for collisions, an object has to has to have a flag to know if collision should be checked. In your case, the member can be checked if its null or not, but in the derived case, the object itself tells whether it can collide or not. In an array/tree, I can either pass the derived object as a argument or pass hitbox as an argument using a get() method.

To be more in depth, I have another class - using the second case

```
class Hitbox : public Object, public Collidable
```

and the Actor class has it as a member

```
class Actor : public Object
{
     Hitbox *box;
};
```

Objects that have collision would have a hitbox instead and this represents your post accurately I think. But what's still getting me is that when I review your example again, does it mean that Hitbox should have a Collidable member instead?

```
class Hitbox
{
     Collidable *collision;
};
```

What I have:
An Actor holds a Hitbox which handles collision

What Hitbox should do:
Inherit Collidable or
Have Collidable as a member

Actor is already following your convention. Should Hitbox do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the second case, as `Object` and `Collidable` are cross-cutting concerns. If you go the `CollidableObject` route, you will probably end up with a combinatorial explosion of classes. It won't be long until you see a `CollidableTrackableClickableBlowuppableObject`.

Since `Collidable` is pure virtual, it is used in this case as an interface, so doesn't have many of the criticisms that argue against multiple inheritance. You are simply stating that an Actor implements the `Collidable` interface.

Comment: You wouldn't have to have a `CollidableTrackableClickableBlowuppableObject` if you did the first; it'd just be one class that inherited from `Collidable`, `Trackable`, `Clickable`, and `Blowuppable`, like the first way, but you wouldn't inherit `Object` like the first. I'm not sure if the first one is more useful; shouldn't all `Clickable`s be drawable to the screen? If you have them all be seperate, you can't tell if your `Object` is clickable or if your `Clickable` is drawable. With the second way, you do know that `Clickable` is drawable.

Comment: You wouldn't have to have a ... if you did the _second_ I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect scenario for the [**strategy pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This is where the English language plays tricks on our minds and makes us think that `CollidableObject` is a valid object to have in this hierarchy. I say collision is more of a behavior than an object, so I'd go with neither of the two.

Prefer composition for this:

```
class Object
{
   CollidableBehavior* collisionBehavior;
}
class Actor : Object
{
   // collisionBehavior = new ActorCollision()
}

class AClassThatDoesntCollide
{
   // collisionBehavior = NULL
}
```

Comment: If the collision behavior depends on the specifics of the Actor class, this won't be very practical. On the other hand if it's an independent attribute, this makes good sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the only point in implementing the 2nd case is if I want to derive
>   from a Collidable without being an Object?

Yes, the second case gives you more flexibility as it allows to separate the interfaces. For example, later you may want an object that is collidable but it is not drawable.

> When is the 1st case ever favorable since the 2nd case offers more
>   flexibility.

The second case offers more flexibility but it is also more complex to design. At the end, you will need virtual inheritance and this is more difficult to handle. However, if your base classes are pure abstract it should not be a problem.

You may see [this](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/037.htm).